# How do I do arithmetic operations between a character and a digit in C without using the ascii code

Tags: c, char

I want to add the character ‘4’ and the digit 3 and have it equal 7 without any library methods if possible
I.e ‘4’ + 3 = 7

Comment: It's impossible without using the character encoded value of the digit, since the value of `'4'` *is* `52` (for ASCII).

Comment: Trivally: `#define UNCHARIFY(ch) (ch&~((1<<3)-1<<4))`. Then `UNCHARIFY('4') + 3;`  :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 11):

For all single digits you can do like:

```
char c = '4';

// If you want to add 3 now you can do like:
int result = c - '0' + 3;
```

Subtracting '0' is the key here. That's it

Comment: i always remember: '0' has ascii hex code: 0x30, '1' is 0x31 and so on, so i do similiar - but more straightforward:  result = c - 0x30 + value

Comment: @JosiP: It is considered bad practice to use `c - 0x30 + value` for this rather than `c - '0' + value` because the former requires ASCII whereas the latter is portable to any C implementation and because the latter expresses intent to work with characters and convert a digit character to its represented number.